# MPI_Scatter : Scatter Eigen Matrix

Tags: mpi, eigen3

I am trying to implement an MPI_Scatter using eigen matrix using following :

```
// get pointer to samples
double *X = prob.x;
// map the samples into the matrix object
MatrixXd globaldata = Map<MatrixXd>(X, dims, nsmp);
MatrixXd localdata;
int size, rank;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

if (rank == 0) {
    printf("Processor %d has data before Scatter \n", rank);
    cout << globaldata<<endl<<endl;
}

MPI_Scatter(globaldata.data(), 1, MPI_DOUBLE, &localdata, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0,
        MPI_COMM_WORLD);

printf("Processor %d has data \n", rank);
cout << localdata << endl;
```

The output of MatrixXd globaldata is :

```
        -1         -1         -1         -1
 -0.997455  -0.996032  -0.998472  -0.996154
  -0.94402  -0.912698  -0.966387  -0.915385
 -0.974555  -0.960317  -0.984721  -0.961538
  -0.46056 -0.0753968  -0.676089   0.423077
         1          1          1          1
```

Then I  try to scatter the eigen Matrix gloaldata using

```
MPI_Scatter(globaldata.data(), 1, MPI_DOUBLE, &localdata, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0,
            MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

However i don't think above is correct. How can i scatter the above eigen matrix column by column so that when i run  `mpirun -np 4 ./mpitest` for example i see each column of eigen matrix mapped to each process or the 2 mapped to each process if np is 2? Is the send_datatype and recv_datatype correct i-e MPI_DOUBLE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MPI_Scatter, the count (which you have as 1) is the number of elements sent to each process. To distribute the matrix evenly amongst "size" processes then you need to set count to 16/size (for your 4x4 matrix example).

This relies on all the data in the matrix being stored as a single contiguous block of memory - you'll need to check that's the case for MatrixXd types, although I'd guess it would be true.

Again, whether the scatter distributes rows or columns depends on your storage order. For standard C arrays, on 4 processes you would send a separate row to each process, not a  column. However, Eigen seems to default to column-major storage (standard for Fortran but not for C) which would then mean you are sending entire columns.

Comment: If i dont use MatrixXd and just use X it still does not work. X is an array of size 4*6. I tried using  
 MPI_Scatter(&X, 4,MPI_DOUBLE, &X1, 4, MPI_DOUBLE, 0,
         MPI_COMM_WORLD);  where X1 is also declared as double *X1; I am running using mpirun -np 4 ./test. It gives me segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate space for the receive buffer. Simply defining a variable as double * doesn't reserve any storage so you will get an error. I think the same is true for your original example - localdata is defined but it looks like no storage space is allocated.

To get the code working, you could try:

```
double X1[24]; // This is more storage than you need but its safe
...
MPI_Scatter(X, 4,MPI_DOUBLE, X1, 4, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD)
```

Although the error is occurring in MPI_Scatter, I think the source of the problem is that there's some confusion here between pointers and allocating arrays.